# memory management error while installing festival 2.4

Tags: festival

I am trying to install festival 2.4 in fedora 24, I have installed the tool with a few warnings alone, when I try to invoke the festival command using "bin/festival" it gives a memory management error on the usage of free() function. I understand it is related to dynamic memory management, but I do not know how to fix it. Please let me the solutions.

Comment: You might find this similar question of interest: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718148/how-to-allocate-more-memory-to-a-process-in-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718148/how-to-allocate-more-memory-to-a-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Memory Management Error is shown along with BSOD, and it could be an annoying problem. The easiest method for this problem is to simply restart your system.

if Memory Management error message still persists, you follow the instructions below:

1. Run Diagnostics to Check Your System for Memory Problems
2. Run SFC/SCANNOW
3. Scan your computer for viruses and malicious programs

You can read more [this tutorial](http://howtoinstallwindows10.com/fix-memory-management-error-windows-10/) to fix this error